# Angular 2 Asp.net MVC Loading issue

Tags: node.js, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, angular

Does anyone know the reason for loading my angular 2 project like the following image.

I get this after I changed the content in the home.component.html file

And how to fix it?
[image]

Below is my HTML for home.component.html page

```html
<div class='panel panel-primary'>
    <div class='panel-heading'>
        Warehouse Management
    </div>
    <div class='panel-body'>
        <div class='table-responsive'>
            <!--<div style="padding-bottom:10px"><button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addUser()">Add</button></div>-->
            <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert" *ngIf="indLoading"><img src="../../images/loading.gif" width="32" height="32" /> Loading...</div>
            <div *ngIf='warehouses && warehouses.length==0' class="alert alert-info" role="alert">No record found!</div>
            <table class='table table-striped' *ngIf='warehouses && warehouses.length'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Territory Code</th>
                        <th>Warehouse Code</th>
                        <!--<th>Gender</th>-->
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let warehouse of warehouses">
                        <td>{{warehouse.TerritoryCode}}</td>
                        <td>{{warehouse.WarehouseCode}}</td>
                        
                        <!--<td>
                            <button title="Edit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="editUser(user.Id)">Edit</button>
                            <button title="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteUser(user.Id)">Delete</button>
                        </td>-->
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="msg" role="alert" class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Error:</span>
            {{msg}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Error: 
[image]

Comment: Check console in browser for possible errors.

Comment: post the code and error

Comment: Added the error. Pls check

Comment: Sorry. added please check.

Comment: in your root html, should be `Index.html`, do you have `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: My root file is _Layout.cshtml. Yes DOCTYPE is there in that file.

Comment: can't figureout what wrong, without looking into more code. [see this article](https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2016/10/08/angular2-using-angular2-with-typescript-for-asp-net-mvc-in-visual-studio-2015/) and try to map your work., also check for necessary `meta` tags, this problem generaly lies in `IE browser`, check in other browsers too.

Comment: It does not depend on browser. It is working fine when I rebuild and run the project. Thanks @anoop